# Default value for subdomain in Routing.yml Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.4

Following is my routing.yml which includes all routes from controller:

Parameters.yml

```
domain: testmultidb.hrd
```

Routing.yml

```
vi_company:
    resource: "@ViCompanyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "admin.{company}.%domain%"
    defaults:
#        company: #any way to  get subdomain name here.
```

now, `{company}` can be anything like `company1, company2, companyn ...` so issue is every time in URL generating i have to pass this `company` parameter

```
<a href="{{ path("vi_company_dashboard", {company: subdomainName } ) }}">DashBoard</a>
```

is there anyway to eliminate this `{company: subdomainName }` while generating URL. so it will get "company1" from admin.company1.testmultidb.hrd, "company2" from admin.company2.testmultidb.hrd

Also is there anyway to restrict any subdomain:

```
vi_company:
    resource: "@ViCompanyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "admin.{company}.%domain%"
    requirements:
#        company: any way to restrict 'super' subdomain here
```

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2):

Router has a RequestContext object, which literally holds context of current request.
This completes lack of parameters with its them when generating the route path.

So if you set the default `company` to RequestContext before generate the route, it might work fine:

```php
$this->get('router.request_context')->setParameter('company', $request->attributes->get('company'));
```

And this code should be worked on all requests via EventDispatcher after RouterListener::onKernelRequest invoked (i.e. priority should be less than 16).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same goal - subdomain to identify customer, prefix to identify language. I wanted the `{domain}` attribute be the same as the input by default with option to override it in my templates.

```
app:
    resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    host:     "{domain}.qufi.net"
    requirements:
        _locale: "%available_locales%"
        domain: "[a-z0-9]+"
```

Issei.M in this thread answers the question, although not a working example is provided. I pasted mine here: http://pastebin.com/kenVw9mv

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

I really can't see how to get {company} as default in the routing config.

But you can still generate a route based on {company} parameters :

```
<a href="{{ path("vi_company_dashboard", {company: app.request.get('company') } ) }}">DashBoard</a>
```

Restricting access to 'super' subdomain can be done in security settings ([see access_control doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/security.html#understanding-how-access-control-works)).

It's supposed to be something like this :

```
security:

    access_control:

        - { path: ^/*, host: admin\.super\.testmultidb\.hrd$, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes i know that i can specify default parameter. what i don't know is how do you set this default parameter dynamic ? subdomain wise like if host is admin.company1.testmultidb.hrd then default value should be "company1" ..